# Show button when scroll up [JS]

Tags: javascript, scroll

I would like to show the button when scroll up. My current script doing this but I have to scroll to the top, and then the button appears. Is there any possible to show the button just shortly after I scrolling up the page?

```
<script>
function showButton() {

    var button  = $('#my-button'), //button that scrolls user to top
        view = $(window),
        timeoutKey = -100;

    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
        if(timeoutKey) {
            window.clearTimeout(timeoutKey);
        }
        timeoutKey = window.setTimeout(function(){

            if (view.scrollTop() > 10) {
                button.fadeOut();
            }
            else {
                button.fadeIn();
            }
        }, 10);
    });
}

$('#my-button').on('click', function(){
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: 10
    }, 10, 'linear');
    return false;
});

//call function on document ready
$(function(){
   showButton();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `offset().top` instead of `scrollTop()`